# primeira vez que instalo o xubuntu, estou tendo um problema quando desligo o pc

Tags: xubuntu

So when I turn the computer off by the operating system or by the shutdown button it restarts, it happened after I installed xubuntu, I already tried to change the bios but it didn't work, so it could be the operating system. And also shows when I turn off or on the machine / dev / sda5 clean is normal

Então quando eu desligo o computador pelo sistema operacional ou pelo botão de desligar ele reinicia, isso aconteceu depois que instalei o xubuntu,
eu já tentei mexer na bios mas não deu certo, então pode ser o sistema operacional.
E também mostra quando desligo ou ligo a maquina /dev/sda5 clean é normal ??
desde já agradeço

Comment: You haven't provided release details   (FYI: this site is english, for non-english I'd suggest a LoCo https://loco.ubuntu.com/ or IRC (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo grub-update
```

This should fix the issue, but if it doesn’t, try the following:

Edit the file at `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Find the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

and add `acpi=force` at the end so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”
```

Save and exit using `:wq`

Finally run,

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and it should be fixed.

Comment: Obrigado, eu fiz tudo isso mas não funcionou.